Proof that the solution to a time dependent wave equation is (anti-)symmetric given (anti-)symmetric boundary conditions
I am unable to prove the following statement (which is numerically motivated).
For a function $F(t_1,t_2)$ fulfilling the following ODE
$$\partial_{t_1}^2F(t_1,t_2) + E(t_1)^2F(t_1,t_2)=0$$
for $(t_1,t_2)\in[t_0,t_f]^2$ with boundary conditions (upper sign for symmetric BC lower for antisymmetric BC)
$$F(t_0,t)=\pm F(t,t_0)=f(t)$$
$$\partial_x F(x,t)|_{x=t_0}=\pm\partial_x F(t,x)|_{x=t_0}$$
the solution is symmetric/antisymmetric, i.e.
$$F(t_1,t_2)=\pm F(t_2,t_1).$$
I do not have any information about what ODE $F$ fulfills in its second argument.
$E$ can be any smooth function. It is not dependent on $t_2$.
Not sure if Physics or Maths SE is the right place for this.
